# Выбрать значение из одной таблицы по значению из другой

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет!

Есть 2 таблицы

levels c колонками lvl(уровень),exp_to_level(опыта до уровня), exp_total(опыт для преодоления планки уровня)

users с колонками login, lvl

Нужно по логину посмотреть какой у него уровень и по уровню из таблицы levels взять exp_total, пробовал использовать следующий код, не получается:

```
$resultlvl = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT exp_total FROM levels JOIN users ON users.lvl = users.login ='".$LOGIN."'");

while ($levels= mysqli_fetch_array($resultlvl)) {
$exp_total.=$levels['exp_total'];
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Я так понимаю таблицы связываются как раз по полю lvl. вот его и пишите в ON `FROM levels JOIN users ON levels.lvl=users.lvl` а потом накладываете дополнительные условия в `WHERE users.login=:login`. И значение лучше подставлять не в виде переменной, а с помощью http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: @Mike спасибо, помогло!